# Building GrapheneOS fails with "Out-Of-Memory"

Tags: android, linux, compiler-errors, out-of-memory

My machine is stuck/hang and generate OOM (Out-Of-Memory: process killed (xxxxxx)......) when I check "dmesg" in terminal.

I try to build GrapheneOS for panther (pixel 7) in my Linux m/c 20.04 (16 GiB RAM, 500+ GiB internal storage). But my machine stuck/hang whenever i run

`m -j4 vendorbootimage target-files-package` instead of
`target-files-package` command.
It generate build.ninja and took long ideal time, and after taking long ideal time, failed.
when I run "dmesg" command in terminal. It prints OOM (Out-Of-Memory: process killed).

Answer (score 0):

The dmesg has already replied to your answer: OOM: Out of Memory, You need to add some RAM, a 32 GB is recommended!

Answer (score 0):

When you compile with N parallel jobs, you need about N-times of the RAM. Try to reduce the number of jobs to one for example `-j1`